# Is this a second-countable space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=[a,b]\subseteq\Bbb R$. Define $Z=X\times\{1,2\}$ such that their opens are
\begin{align*}
    Z_1 &=\Big\{ \big((c,d)_I\times\{1,2\}\big)\setminus\{(x,2)\} \ \big|\ x\in(c,d)_I\subseteq[a,b]_I\Big\},\\
    Z_2 &=\Big\{\{(x,2)\} \ \big|\ x\in[a,b]_I\Big\},\\
    Z_3 &=\Big\{ \big([a,d)_I\times\{1,2\}\big)\setminus\{(a,2)\} \ \big|\ [a,d)_I\subset[a,b]_I\Big\},\\
    Z_4 &=\Big\{ \big((c,b]_I\times\{1,2\}\big)\setminus\{(b,2)\} \ \big|\ (c,b]_I\subset[a,b]_I\Big\}.
\end{align*}
where $(x, y)_I$ denotes the interval $(x,y)$. Is this a second-countable space? I think is not since it is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ (an open square intersecting $Z_4$ and a point of $Z_2$ makes an interval and not a singular point), but still not sure on how to proceed with this problem.

Also, does this topology has a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is not second countable.

Given any basis $\mathcal{B}$, by definition for each $x \in [a, b]_I$ there is $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $(x, 2) \in B \subseteq \{ (x, 2) \}$, which means that $\{ (x, 2) \} = B \in \mathcal{B}$. Thus $Z_2 \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, which makes $\mathcal{B}$ uncountable.

More generally, if in a topological space there is an uncountable family of disjoint open subsets, the space is not second countable.

Comment: Makes sense. I think that with the same argument we can show that the space is not separable. Also, just for curiosity, since it is not second countable, does it implies that it is not first-countable?

Comment: It is, indeed, not separable, but it is first countable. To see it, consider each $z \in Z$ separately and look at intervals with rational endpoints.

Comment: But what about a point in $Z_2$? We can not place an interval contained in a singular point, which is open

Comment: For points of the form $(x, 2)$, the singleton $\mathcal{B} = \{ (x, 2) \}$ is a local basis. It doesn't matter it's not an interval because it satisfies the definition of a local basis.